# How do I get my Excel data into Word's ContentControl

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have placed a Plain Text Content Control on my Document.

I opened the Macro and have the following code

```
Sub PrefillDocument()
'
' PrefillDocument Macro
'
'
    Dim docName As ContentControls
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = ActiveDocument.Path & "\CountyData.xlsx"
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
    MsgBox exWb.Sheets("4").Cells(1, 2) // Works

    ' Having problems trying to get the data from Excel into the content control
    Set docName = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Name") // Get 

    docName.Item.Title = exWb.Sheets("4").Cells(1, 2)
    MsgBox docName.Title
    'ActiveDocument.FormFields("Name").Result =
    'ThisDocument.m_name.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Member's Data").Cells(2, 1)

    exWb.Close
    Set exWb = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have been told NOT to use any legacy controls so I am forced to use the newer ContentControls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docName is a collection of controls, and in this case, Word isn't going to let you apply a Title to every control in the Collection.

So you will need to iterate, e.g.

```
Dim cc as ContentControl
For Each cc In docName
  cc.Title = exWb.Sheets("4").Cells(1, 2)
Next
```

or you could probably drop your docName declaration and do

```
Dim cc as ContentControl
For Each cc In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("Name")
  cc.Title = exWb.Sheets("4").Cells(1, 2)
Next
```

For the question you posted in the comments, to update the actual content of the Control rather than the title, you need to know that the content is represented by a Word Range, and that you need to set the text of the range, e.g.

```
cc.Range.Text = exWb.Sheets("4").Cells(1.2)
```

You will still need to iterate through the collection of controls.

Comment: I need the printable text to change to the actual name. The title did change but the actual printable text didnt change

Comment: Assuming you mean the *content* of the control, that's a different question, but all you need to do is assign to a different property of the control - you can look up the properties from the VB Editor via View->Object Browser - it's a very useful tool when working with VBA. I will modify my Answer.